# Classnotfound Exception when starting Opendaylight on WIndows

Tags: java, windows, classnotfoundexception, opendaylight

When I start Opendaylight Nitrogen (Karaf 0.7.0 or 0.7.1) I get the error that `main class ...\etc\odl.java.security cannot be found`.

As source of the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ..\karaf-0/7/1\bin\//\etc\odl\java\security` is mentioned.

I have **Windows 10** and **Java 9**. I also tried it with **Java 8** which also didn't work.

Hope you could help me with is issue.

Comment: what's to help? it's looking for a class you don't have in your classpath

Comment: the java.security is located in the specified path

Comment: java.security is not a class.

Comment: On my co-workers computer Opendaylight starts without problems. There I made the same steps. I realy have no idea what to change when starting it from the shell.

Comment: so ... on your co-workers computer, the missing class is in the ClassPath ... verify your configuration with his

Comment: Sorry for the question, but where can I find this configuration? With echo %path% the output is nearly the same. Also %JAVA_HOME% is equal.

Comment: check the path inside your java_home, and his, check that you have the same versions/jars in there. if you're running from within an ide, check both configurations of those

Comment: AH ok, on his Computer Java 1.8.0 is installed. It seems that the new Opendaylight version is only working with old Java versions.

Comment: I very much doubt that. most likely, there are some classes manually added on the other machine.

Comment: I hope that the next versions of ODL will work with Java 9. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: there is no reason to believe this version doesn't work with Java 9 ... unless you can verify that the class you are missing is indeed removed in Java 9, and is not a part of the path that is handled locally on your machine(s)

Comment: The Java 1.8 folder has completely different files as the version 9. I dont know which one causes the problem. The odl.java.security is part of Opendaylight and in the same place on both computers.

Comment: nice to know, but odl.java.security is not a class, so that is not the actual issue. You'll need to look into the stacktrace which specific class can not be found.

Comment: ^^ how can I log and open the stacktrace when running from the shell?

Comment: You should be able to look at the logs and see the stacktrace in data/logs/karaf.log.

Comment: I had the same issue. Turned out that the odl's folder name was the issue. I named it "odl nitrogen" but karaf was not able to deal with the space. After renaming it to "nitrogen" it worked.